# JavaScript support for OO Polymorphism?

Tags: javascript

I would like to understand if JavaScript really support Polymorphism ? With function arguments function overloading appears ok but function overriding in classical OO using inheritance ? Is it also supported by JavaScript
Any input pointers would be helpful.

Comment: @Asad I checked this quetion and its about function overloading i am asking about inheritance based polymorphism ... overrriding and all

Comment: Well, JavaScript doesn't really have classes at all, so technically it doesn't have methods to override either. All properties inherited from a prototype can be overwritten at any point in an instance's construction or service life.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is an object oriented language, but not through classical OO. It supports it through prototyping. I would do some research of Java Script and prototyping - Start there